# How to handle alt+p keyboardEvent on macOS browsers

Tags: javascript, macos, keyboard-events, keycode, alt-key

I'ld like to listen the following keyboardEvent : **alt + p**

```
if (event.altKey && event.key === "p") {

  doThis(stuff)

}
```

Problem is that in OSX **(alt+p) === "π"**

so I wrote this ugly condition for Mac OSX users

```
 if (
      (event.altKey && event.key === "π") ||
      (event.altKey && event.key === "p")
    ) {

       doThis(stuff)

}
```

It works *AND* it's ugly =D

**So if anyone has a better way to handle this please give me a hint !**

*USEFULL REMINDER: keyCode and charCode are DEPRECATED*

Comment: Note that this issue exists for many special characters on MacOSX**

Comment: What about [`event.code`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code)?  MDN says that ignores keyboard layout.

Comment: @zero298 not necessarily a good thing - it means if people have a different layout (e.g. azerty), you will be receiving "Q" when they type "A"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that 'keyCode' and 'charCode' are deprecated & have been replaced by '.code' & '.key'. so event.key is just fine =D